# flowplayer playlist - set a splash image of first frame of first video in a playlist

Tags: php, video, splash-screen, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer to play videos on my site, and i have configured a playlist with 4 videos, similar to this:  [Flowplayer Playlist](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html)

But what i saw is that, the video portrays a Play button on the video, upon clicking on which, i can play the video.

Instead, i would like to have the first frame of the first video as the splash screen on the video.

I tried with these settings, but they did not work:

```
$(function() {

    // setup player without "internal" playlists
    $f("player2", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
        clip: {baseUrl: '', autoPlay: false, autoBuffering: true, start: 62} 


    // use playlist plugin. again loop is true
    }).playlist("div.petrol", {loop:false});

});
```

And the video playlist is configured as:

```
<div class="clips petrol" style="float:left">

    <!-- single playlist entry -->
    <a href="a.flv" class="first">
        Palm trees and the Sun
        <span>HTTP streaming</span>
        <em>0:20 min</em>

    </a>

    <a href="b.flv">
        Happy feet inside a car
        <span>HTTP streaming</span>
        <em>0:20 min</em>   
    </a>

............


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this playlist tutorial? It explains how you can make a playlist with static images to use as the splash screen to start the video (i.e. you can create your own play button icon on top of the first frame of the video).

http://flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/playlist.html

Also, there is a tutorial on splash screens that explains how you can initially display a static image which when you click it, it will activate the Flowplayer video.

http://static.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/splash-image.html

Regarding using the first frame of your video for the static image, it says;

> If you have lots of videos you can use FFMPEG to grab images from your
>   video file without the hassle of making a doing all that work
>   manually.

It also has links to the "Multiple players on a same page" tutorial, if you want an alternative to using a single video player to display a list of videos.